# Deploy artifacts in my local Maven repository to a remote repository

Tags: java, maven, build

I am using Maven as a build tool. Is there a way to deploy the artifacts present in my local maven repository (which I install via a 3rd party tool), to my remote Nexus repository ?

Thanks

Comment: Which kind of 3rd party tool? Just use mvn `deploy:deploy-file` or manually upload them into Nexus.

Comment: The 3rd party I use extracts the artifacts created on a build server to my local repo. However the project is too big to deploy each artifact manually. Is there a command that I can run on all the source code, and that, instead of compiling all the source code, uses the artifacts in my local maven repo and then deploy on the remote repo?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy a whole bunch of artifacts with their poms as well as multiple artifacts using classifiers, you could use the tool we created in the Apache Flex project which is part of the Mavenizer tool, that we use to deploy entire repositories or parts of them ...

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Apache+Flex+SDK+Mavenizer

Code available at: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flex-utilities.git

The SDKDeployer uses a local maven installation and acts as a wrapper to the maven `deploy:deploy-file` plugin, the SDKInVMDeployer does the same but without Maven utilizing the Maven libs directly (Is quite a lot faster)